# Receive HTTP POST response by python

Tags: php, python, html, http, post

I use the following example:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

When I run it from browser, 
I see the results in the browser:

```
Welcome John
Your email address is john.doe@example.com
```

When I run python POST http request:

```
import httplib, urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'@name': 'John','@email': 'John.doe@example.com'})
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/html"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("10.0.0.201")
conn.request("POST","/welcome.php",params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print "Status"
print response.status
print "Reason"
print response.reason
print "Read"
print response.read()
conn.close()
```

I see the following:

```
Status
200
Reason
OK
Read
<html>
<body>

Welcome <br>
Your email address is: 
</body>
</html>
```

The question is:
How to receive POST request data in python?

Comment: Why the painful route driving the `HTTPConnection` manually when there is the `urllib2` library, or you can install [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)?

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong form names *and* the wrong HTTP method. There are no `@` characters at their starts:

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'name': 'John','email': 'John.doe@example.com'})
```

Next, the form you point to uses *GET*, not *POST* as the handling method, so you'll have to add these parameters to the URL instead:

```
conn.request("GET", "/welcome.php?" + params, '', headers)
```

You are doing yourself a disservice by trying to drive the `HTTPConnection()` manually. You could use [`urllib2.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) instead for example:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from urllib import urlencode

params = urlencode({'name': 'John','email': 'John.doe@example.com'})
response = urlopen('http://10.0.0.201/welcome.php?' + params)
print response.read()
```

or you could make use of the [`requests` library](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (separate install) to make it yourself much easier still:

```
import requests

params = {'name': 'John','email': 'John.doe@example.com'}
response = requests.get('http://10.0.0.201/welcome.php', params=params)
print response.content
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `urllib`, use the `requests` library as Martijn suggested. It will make things much simpler.

Check out the documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the "@" and it works:

```
Status
200
Reason
OK
Read
<html>
<body>

Welcome John<br>
Your email address is: John.doe@example.com
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you Martijn Pieters.

As for POST method, i used the example for infrastructure testing purposes.
Finally i need to fill mysql database and retrieve data from it over php using python script.
What is the best method for it?
Why is HTTPConnection() not recommended?